# Transform data with django ORM

Tags: sql, django, orm

I have the following model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    material = models.CharField(max_length=20])
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

With data as follows:

```
john, 2011-01-21, GOLD, 10.00
blair, 2011-01-21, GOLD, 20.00
peter, 2011-01-21, SILVER, 21.00
peter, 2011-01-22, GOLD, 11.00
john, 2011-01-22, SILVER, 12.00
```

I would like to:

- aggregate (addition) by material per date
- produce an entry per day, with all the available materials (not known in advance)

As follows:

```
DATE        GOLD   SILVER
2011-01-21  30.00  21.00
2011-01-22  11.00  12.00
```

(dates not present in the input data will not get an output row)

How can this be achieved in SQL? With Django ORM?

Note: my database backend is Postgres

Comment: Are you concerned about the timezones of the datetime field? It's possible that one entry was for a different date locally than another entry.

Comment: @schillingt: no, let's assume timezones are no issue

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you. As a heads up, if you need to respect timezones, this becomes a much more difficult thing to do via the ORM.

```
from django.db.models import DateField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
Entry.objects.annotate(
    d=Cast('date', DateField())
).values('d', 'material').annotate(
    total=Sum('price')
)
```

Comment: Would this produce entries with **three rows**, `DATE`, `GOLD` and `SILVER`?

Comment: No. This will return the entries annotated on date and material with the total price. Use `.first().__dict__` to see how it's exactly working with your data.